# Do these properties already make $d(x,y)$ a metric?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have proved that if $d:X\times X\to\mathbb{R}$ has the properties

$$M1: d(x,y)=0\Leftrightarrow x=y$$
and
$$M2: d(x,y)\leq d(x,z) + d(y,z) \; \forall x,y,z\in X$$

, that already ensure that $d(x,y)$ is a metric. [See this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3235802/positivity-and-symmetry-from-defination-of-metric)

Now I wonder, if it would be even enough if we not call for $M2$, but for the regular triangle inequality
$$M2': d(x,y)\leq d(x,z) + d(z,y) \; \forall x,y,z\in X$$

I am pretty sure that this is not enough for $d(x,y)$ to be a metric, since I don't think we can prove symmetry. However, I can not prove that this is not enough. I do not have any counterexamples. I don't even have any examples for a function that has properties $M1$ and $M2'$ and is NOT already a metric. (or already symmetric, what is equal in this case)

I'd appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a set with two points, say $X = \{a,b\}$. Define a function $d$ on $X \times X$ by setting:
$$
d(a,a)=0, \qquad d(b,b)=0, \qquad d(a,b)=1, \qquad d(b,a)=2.
$$
Clearly $d$ satisfies $M1$, and you can check by exhaustion that $d$ satisfies $M2'$. But, of course, $d$ is not symmetric.

---

Note: to show $M2'$, you can also be a bit clever. Let $x,y,z \in X$. Since $X$ has two elements, $z$ must be either $x$ or $y$. If $z=x$, then
$$
d(x,z)+d(z,y)=d(x,x)+d(x,y)=d(x,y).
$$
And if $z=y$, then
$$
d(x,z)+d(z,y)=d(x,y)+d(y,y)=d(x,y).
$$
In either case, we get $d(x,y) = d(x,z)+d(z,y)$.

EDIT: In this "clever" proof of $M2'$, I neglected to consider the case where $x=y$, in which case $z$ may not equal $x=y$. But then $d(x,y)=0$ by definition of $d$, so the triangle inequality still holds here.